# Broadcast calendar in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I' need `code snippet` for rendering broadcast calendar in Asp.NET MVC View.
Input will be ***Month*** & ***Year***.
[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFlb3.png) 
Content is for illustrate purpose. 
But, I need to render actual dates in squares.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please post what you currently have

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no "snippet" that will solve your problem. Calendars are complicated to deal with. Dates in general are a pain to work with, especially when you cross timezones and daylight savings and whatnot.

To do what you're asking, you should learn a library that solves some of these issues for you. For JS, something like:

https://fullcalendar.io/

Depending on your client/server frameworks, there may be 3rd party widgets that handle some of this for you as well. For example, Telerik offers a wide array of options for various frameworks:

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index

If this is for internal business purposes and not a custom/public site, hosted solutions like Sharepoint offer easy-to-implement "no-code" solutions that allow you to setup an event tracking calendar with a few clicks.